Spring Authorization Server: How to login from external API?
My project is using Spring boot 3 and using multi modules structure. Here is my structure:


core: common code like utils, config
auth: has an login API that using RestTemplate to call external API for login. After login successfully, return access token like this format:

{
  "accessToken": "${JWT_token}",
  "refreshToken": "${JWT_token}",
  "accExpiredTime": 1729656803,
  "refExpiredTime": 1730175203
}


asset, order: user must be logged in before call APIs in both modules

I'm researching about OAuth2 for authen and authorization. Because I don't want to public any API in asset, order, ekyc. I have some grant type:

password: use this grant type if call API asset and order
client_credentials: use this grant type if call API ekyc

I'm newbie of OAuth2 so I don't have any experience to build an auth module for enterprise. I want to apply Authorization Server for auth module, and Resource server for others. Anyone could show me how to implement OAuth2 for my case, please? Or give me a tutorial links please? I researched about this but deadline so close.
